# Twitter Bootstrap lightbox not working properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, lightbox

I am trying to use Twitter Bootstrap Light-box.

My code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>LightBox</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-combined.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-lightbox.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <h2>HELLO</h2>
                    <div id="lightBoxId" class="lightbox hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="lightbox-content">
                            <img src="cubsimba141.gif" />
                            <div class="lightbox-caption">
                                <p>This is test image</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a data-toggle="lightbox" href="#lightBoxId" class="span2 thumbnail">
                        <img src="cubsimba141.gif" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap-lightbox.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Above code able to show me Light-Box after clicking on thumbnail image. When I click outside that light box it's need to hide that light-box, but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** I fixed your code. I had to change the html for the modal. Have a look at this [updated link](http://www.bootply.com/0Z4kZLOq0o). Also attaching the code below.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle-modal").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('toggle');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<h1>Modal Simple Demo</h1>
<!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Launch Demo Modal</a>

<!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
                <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems that you forgot to make it functional with javascript. I created this demo. Have a look... [Demo Link](http://www.bootply.com/kGA6UV7z52).

Comment: that button makes a trick. But still on outside click of that pop-box did't hide that box. May be i'm missing any Js/css file, can you help me for that ?

Comment: Hmm. It does for me. By default it is supposed to close when clicking outside of the modal. Try to update the code with this `<a data-toggle="modal" href="#lightBoxId" data-keyboard="true" data-backdrop="true" class="span2 thumbnail">`.